# opencv imread changes image

Tags: image, opencv, bitmap

I have a very basic test case:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
int main(){
auto image = cv::imread("input.bmp");
cv::imwrite("output.bmp");
}
```

## input.bmp

[image: input.bmp]

## output.bmp

[image: output.bmp]

As you can see, they look completely different. Whats happening here?

I tried with `cv::imread("input.bmp", -1)` to read the image unchanged but that doesn't help.
I've tried with other bmp images and somtimes it works, weirdly enough. I haven't figured out when it works and when it doesn't.

EDIT: link to the original file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mG3I-G0sS0qi3QBuvQQK9Oa9yPq1Uoif/view?usp=sharing

Comment: is it possible for you to upload the original bmp file? Did you check the color format etc. with an application like irfanView or GIMP?

Comment: I updated my question with a link to the original file. 
I don't know what you mean by checking the color format, sorry. I have GIMP installed. Maybe my image is just corruped...

Comment: sorry, cant download from google drive. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format at section pixel-format. I expect that opencv cant handle all of them, so you might be able to find out which color / pixel-format your file is. Most common one (and probably opencv can handle it) is 24BPP. Maybe you can also find out the subtype.

Comment: I was able to circumvent the problem by reading and writing the same image with the imagemagick library. I'm not doing anything in between, just reading and writing with imagemagick. Then I can read and write the image with opencv without it changing the image. This takes up to 200ms unfortunately, so I would rather have a better solution, but for now it works.

Comment: I will read into the Wikipedia article about the pixel-format, thank you. Although I'm not sure what to do if I find out opencv can't handle 24BPP. Thank you for your time anyways!

Comment: "I'm not sure what to do" -- first step would be filing a bug in OpenCVs issue tracker. Anyway, looking at the header, the original image uses 10 colour palette and RLE8 compression.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to circumvent the problem by reading and writing the same image with the imagemagick library. I'm not doing anything in between, just reading and writing with imagemagick. Then I can read and write the image with opencv without it changing the image. This takes up to 200ms unfortunately, so I would rather have a better solution, but for now it works.